# Hackerrank Python Nested Lists exercise

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying the following problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem

My approach:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        x.append([score, name])
x.sort()
minimum_score = x[0][0]
for a in x:
    if a[0] == minimum_score:
        x.remove(a)
second_minimum_score = x[0][0]
for b in x:
    if b[0] == second_minimum_score:
        print(b[1])
```

Here whenever there are 2 or more minimum scores the code fails
eg inputs:

```
5
Harsh
20
Beria
20
Varun
19
Kakunami
19
Vikas
21
```

any idea?

Comment: You can put all the scores in a dict and the get the value for second lowest key.

Comment: Never ever modify a list you're iterating on...

Comment: Please include the problem description plus expected (and actual) output here in the question. Links can break, making your question useless.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers when they solve your problem (checkmark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your second loop, you're removing item from a list you're iterating on, which is *always* a bad idea.

Here is a slight modification of your code where the second `for` loop has been turned into a `while` loop.

```py
x = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    x.append([score, name])
x.sort()
minimum_score = x[0][0]
while x != [] and x[0][0] == minimum_score:
    x.pop(0)
if x != []:
    second_minimum_score = x[0][0]
    for b in x:
        if b[0] == second_minimum_score:
            print(b[1])
```

Output:

```
Beria
Harsh
```

Comment: In the while loop statement what is  x !=[]? What does that '!' mean? ps i am trying to learn python on my own so i dont have much idea about all the functions

Comment: @ManasGhandat `x != []` means `x` is *not* the empty list.  This is required, otherwise the test right after (`x[0][0] == minimum_score`) would cause an error if the list is empty.  Actually, the code after the `while` loop may also crash in that case.  I added a test to avoid that.